# IE 9 text area linebreak issue

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

When am copying a text from IE9 **text area** field,and pasting it in a notepad,all line-breaks are disappearing,its coming as a single line even though it has more than 1 line like explained below,this issue is only in Ie9 not with any other browser or other versions of IE.

Original Text :

```
 abcdefghi
 jklmnopqr
 stuvwxyz
```

after copying it into notepad,It's coming as:

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

thanks.

Comment: *Looks* like IE9 is using plain `\n` instead of `\r\n` as its textarea newline delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use following snippet to replace current clipboard data to be copied/cutted on IE:

```
$('textarea').on("copy cut", function (e) {
    if (window.clipboardData) {
        var sel = this.value.substring(this.selectionStart, this.selectionEnd);
        window.clipboardData.setData("Text", sel.replace(/\n/g, "\r\n"));
        if(e.type === "cut") this.value = this.value.substring(0, this.selectionStart) + this.value.substring(this.selectionEnd);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

### --DEMO--